The intersection of all open sets containing $x$ is $\{x\}\$
I was given this question: If $(X, d)$ is a metric space, then the intersection of all open sets sets containing a point $x \in X$ is $\{x\}$.
I gave the following solution: Suppose for a contradiction that the intersection of all open sets containing $x$ is not $\{x\}$. Then there exists another element, say $y \in X$ such that $y \neq x$, belonging to this intersection. If that is the case, then $y$ must belong to all open sets containing $x$. However, that is impossible because then $y \in B_\epsilon(x)$, $\forall \epsilon > 0$. This necessarily implies that $y = x$. Therefore, there must exist some positive $\epsilon$ where $y \notin B_\epsilon(x)$. This creates a contradiction.
My doubt stems from two places. Is my negated statement appropiate for a contradiciton? I have many times in the past not negated properly, leading to incorrect proofs. Is there anything missing such as to obscure my proof? All in all, I believe my proof is correct. Any feedback is appreciated!

Enfield, your proof is correct but you could write it in a better way, in fact it is not necessary to proceed by contradiction.

Every metric space is Hausdorff, that should do the trick.

"This necessarily implies..." Why?  That seems mere assertion. For each $y\neq x,$ it is very easy to find a specific $\epsilon>0.$

I suggest a little modification : After you get hold of your $y$, you know it must be in all open sets containing $y$. But then how about $B_{d}(x)$ where $d=\frac12d(x,y)$? This gives you a contradiction.

The negation of the assertion you are trying to prove is that there exists a metric space $(X,d)$ and an $x\in X$ such that ${x}$ is not the intersection of the open sets containing $x$. But, it seems a little strange to be studying metric spaces if you haven't yet mastered how to negate statements. For what's it worth, I learnt basic logic as a undergraduate student from the book Advanced Calculus by Loomis and Sternberg. The first 10 or so pages are very useful.

It's correct, but you really don't need a proof by contradiction here. A direct proof where you just show a two sided inclusion will look better, and more clear. Sometimes contradiction is necessary, but in this case it doesn't really add anything except extra words. Instead of assuming by contradiction that another element $y$ exists, you can just write directly that if $y$ belongs to all open sets then $y=x$.

@joe no reason to be rude. A person can know how to negate something and still get a negation wrong or feel unsure about it.

I wasn't trying to be rude. Apologies if it came across that way.

I don't get why people are saying this is correct. It is not correct. This is because you are skipping the big assertion: $x \neq y$ implies $d(x,y)>0.$ As written now, the big step is argued merely by assertion. The assertion is true, but it doesn't follow without a specific argument why.

@ThomasAndrews: That $x\neq y$ implies $d(x,y)>0$ follows immediately from the axioms of a metric space, one of which asserts that $d(x,y)=0$ iff $x=y$ (at least, this is one of the axioms in the presentations that I'm used to).

@ThomasAndrews Indeed, a few details are missing, but they are simple, and I believe OP probably knows why the result follows. So I decided not to point it out, but focus on that it's better not to try to prove everything by contradiction. (which is unfortunately a habit that quiet many students develop at the beginning of their studies)

@joe yes, it is the definition of metric spaces, my point is, it is the reason the big step is true, and leaving that reason out makes the step mere assertion. "This necessarily implies..." is very hand-wavy, and does not once invoke the specific part of the definition that the proof needs.
